# Как конфигурировать сборщик проектов Gulp?

Tags: gulp, bower, frontend, workflow

Здравствуйте!

Вот смотрите, если использовать bower и gulp в процессе разаботки своего проекта!

Как правило, в начале имеем структуру подобную этой:

- Built - папка продакшена.
- Src - папка исходников.
- gulp, bower, pakage, git ....

В папке исходников имеем папки **style** **js** **img** ... 
Внутри js, например, папка vendor, куда bower и будет складывать все скаченные плагины.

Ок, да! Но как же нам сконфигурировать gulp задачу на построение проекта в папку Built? 
Взять тот же JQ, который в лежит в **SRC/JS/VENDOR/JQ/....**

При построении продакшен версии нам нужно же вытащить один минимизированный jq-файл и запихнуть его в **built/js/vendor/jq.min.js**

А если у нас 5+ различный плагинов, и у каждого еще есть стили, все они по папкам лежат в **SRC/JS/VENDOR/**.  Как тогда конфигурируют buid папку? Как правильно поступить и перенести из src в билд? Или, может, есть другой подход?

(Я обычно в gulp конфигугрирую ivereload css-компиляцию, и перенос HTML и все,.. а все плагины качаю руками и переношу сразу в build папку, но хочется как-то автоматизировать этот процесс.)

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Качай bower-ом пакеты и потом так. Для gulp нужны concat, main-bower-files, gulp-concat, gulp-filter и, возможно, gulp-order, чтобы сохранить порядок js файлов.

```
    var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  filter = require('gulp-filter'),
  order = require('gulp-order'),
  mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files')
;

gulp.task('scripts:vendor', function () {
  var vendors = mainBowerFiles();

  return gulp.src(vendors)
     .pipe(filter('**.js'))
     .pipe(order(vendors))
     .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
  ;
})
```

Тут еще [подобный вариант](http://erundy.net/gulp-%D0%B8-bower-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B8/).